# env variables are not defined in next.js

Tags: environment-variables, next.js

I created .env.local file and placed env variables as follow:

```
  EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=service_id
  EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=template_id
  EMAILJS_USER_ID=user_id
```

but they are undefined when i use process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to access those environment variables? Client or server side?

Comment: @juliomalves in client side

Comment: See [@Nik020's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370472/1870780), that's most likely your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you should use prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC` if what you want is to use vars in client.

example `NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR=123`

Comment: those are api keys so i want to use as environment variables

Comment: Hi, you should use NEXT_PUBLIC like a prefix and should works.